# Linking input file with variable stored in it to several function files

Tags: matlab

I have code which is in multiple function files, input to these functions are stored in one file called `inputfile.m`(script file), in which I assigned some constant values to the inputs. These values act as a input to several function files named `degree_eq.m`(function file).

How I can write the code so that every time of execution, function files takes the required inputs from the `inputfile.m`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example demonstrating your use case.

Comment: In inputs.m following values are stored a = 5; b = 8; c = 10;  in the below mentioned ways I have to use my stored values.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two functions, one with your inputs (`inputfile`) and one where you do stuff (`do_stuff`).

```
function [a,b,c] = inputfile()
%define your constants
a=10;
b=100;
c=8.3;


function z = do_stuff()
[a, b, c] = inputfile() %takes the inputs from inputfile.m
z = a*c - b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the fact that matlab variables are persistent outside their scope. Lets say you have 6 constants a,b,c,d,e,f defined in input file. So what can be done is, write a top script called top.m which would be something like

```
inputfile
degree_eq1(a,b,c)
degree_eq2(c,d,e)
```

Answer (score 0):

A third approach (combining Nirvedh Meshram and qbzenker answers) is to call an input script inside your MATLAB functions.

The *advantage* is that you do not have to specify which parameters are needed from or specified in your input script, but this is a *disadvantage* too, because the needed inputs are not made explicit. So, it is much more error prone. I only recommend this approach for a large number of input variables.

*inputfile.m*:

```
a = 5;
b = 8;
c = 10;
```

*degree_eq.m*:

```
function d = degree_eq()
    inputfile;
    d = a + b + c;
end
```

As an **alternative**, you can specify which input file to use:

*degree_eq.m*:

```
function d = degree_eq(inputFilename)
    eval(inputFilename);
    d = a + b + c;
end
```

and call it as follows:

```
degree_eq('inputfile');
```